# Adding Metadata to gcc generated executable

Tags: gcc, metadata, compiler-flags

Is there a way to compile a c or c++ project with gcc on Windows in which you can set the output executable to have Metadata stating the author, license, etc similar to a visual Studio project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be helpful to you:

[GCC on Windows: Set "Description" field of C executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598633/gcc-on-windows-set-description-field-of-c-executable)

**PS:I would have commented it but **does not have enough points.**